# Float elements next to eachover while ignoring parent width?

Tags: css, html, width, parent

I've run in to this problem before, but i can't remember what the question was called and i can't find a relevant solution, so here we go again.

I need to float two boxes to the left. These boxes have a static width, the same width as the parent. What happens now is that the boxes stack beneath eachother instead of floating, because the parent isn't wide enough.

Here is a (rough) illustration of what i want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwe7G.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code using `white-space: nowrap` along with `display: inline-block`. If you really need to do it with `float: left`, do what @Kurt suggested since it should work. But I really believe `inline-block` is the right approach here.

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvNEn/2/) or look at the code here:

```
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: That sound like exactly what i'm looking for! Let me give that a shot.

Comment: For some reason it still gets pushed down below. Any ideas why?

Comment: @querty, I updated all the answer based on your comments. Take a look and I hope it helps.

Comment: Kudos to you, exactly what i needed!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't quite work as expected yet. Take a look at the live site here: `http://goo.gl/PcHj2`. Look at `.slide-1` and `.slide-2` within  `.slider`. For some reason `.slide-2` jumps down below `.slide-1`. I don't know why, but it doesn't jump down all the way down, and it's pushed a few pixels to the right as well. Any ideas? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: I didn't realize i had to set `vertical-align: top;` for it to display correctly. Although still pushed like 3px to the right, it's now at the top at least.

Comment: And the out-of-nowhere "margin" that pushed it to the right was caused by the whitespace between the elements. That's obviously why you added the `font-size` properties. I didn't think that far, so i removed them. Works good now, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm happy it finally worked. And yes, the `font-size: 0` is a trick because of the whitespace size. Since this size is based on the `font-family` and `font-size` of the container, we can't deal with it only with negative margins (as some people suggests around the web). I believe this `0` trick for the container is easy yet useful.

Comment: Yes, i did some research and a lot of people tend to go with negative margins. `Font-size` is a much better solution in this case, since it doesn't matter what `font-family` or size you have, it will always workd. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to do this "cleanly" is to have this structure:

```
.window
  .parent
    .child
    .child
```

The parent's `width` is sum of all of its children, while `window` has the width of one child.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `white-space: nowrap` method to work, you'll need a container in between your parent and child items with `position: absolute;`. The children items will need to have `position: relative;` and you will need to assign a height to the top parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/79LWk/3/